# Does baking soda help reducing pesticides from fruits and vegetables?

Tags: pesticides, fruit, soda, vegetables

It seems to be effective with some pesticides on apples:

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jafc.7b03118

I cannot find other studies related to other fruits and vegetables.

Comment: Washing with plain water will reduce pesticides.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I quickly browsed through the article, maybe I do not understand what it really says but I would interpret the diagram Fig. 3.(c) on page 9478 as saying that washing with tap water for 2 minutes reduces the "quantity" of pesticides on the apple from 1350 to 900 or so.
So you are correct that it reduced the amount of pesticides, but only by 30%!!
Unfortunately the other 2 minute long treatments are similarly ineffective, and it seems that only prolonging the wash really helps. 15 minutes (with NHCO_3, no tap water value available) brings the pesticide amount practically to 0.